# the iron-icon not visible with a Master-Detail view generate with Vaadin app starter

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have generate a new Vaadin Flow application with **Vaadin app starter** https://start.vaadin.com/welcome with a **Master-Detail view**.

I have only launch the code generate by "Vaadin" on Windows 10.

```java
     grid.addColumn("occupation").setAutoWidth(true);
        TemplateRenderer<SamplePerson> importantRenderer = TemplateRenderer.<SamplePerson>of(
                "<iron-icon hidden='[[!item.important]]' icon='vaadin:check' style='width: var(--lumo-icon-size-s); height: var(--lumo-icon-size-s); color: var(--lumo-primary-text-color);'></iron-icon><iron-icon hidden='[[item.important]]' icon='vaadin:minus' style='width: var(--lumo-icon-size-s); height: var(--lumo-icon-size-s); color: var(--lumo-disabled-text-color);'></iron-icon>")
                .withProperty("important", SamplePerson::isImportant);
        grid.addColumn(importantRenderer).setHeader("Important").setAutoWidth(true);
```

But in 2 different PC on Windows 10, the iron-icon (check and minus) in the column "important" is not visible. **No error in logs**.

[image: Image with check and minus is not visible]

Have you a solution?

Comment: Similar: [*HTML icons that worked fine in Vaadin 20 longer work in Vaadin 21*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69936586/642706).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Vaadin 14 to 20.**

Vaadin icons are not used in the application except in the renderer.
As it's not used in the java code you should add this annotation on top of the  Master-Detail class:

```
@Uses(Icon.class)
```

I will open a ticket to fix it in start.vaadin.com

**For Vaadin 21+**

Vaadin 21 is starting to replace Polymer components. iron-icon is not available anymore and has been replaced by vaadin-icon.
In this case the starter has not been updated.

You can fix it by changing the template and replace iron-icon with vaadin-icon.

You will also need to add the annotation to be sure that it's working in production Mode. I currently don't know the replacement for Vaadin 21.

```
@Uses(Icon.class)
```

Comment: Thanks. I only added @Uses(Icon.class) but it doesn't seem enough. And @Uses is deprecated in vaadin 21.

Comment: In 21, i have had **@Uses(Icon.class)** and modify  **iron-icon** by **vaadin-icon** in the template : **it works!!** Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Include these import statements in your view-name.ts file

import '@vaadin/icon';
import '@vaadin/vaadin-lumo-styles/vaadin-iconset.js';
import '@vaadin/icons';
```