# HTML icons that worked fine in Vaadin 20 longer work in Vaadin 21

Tags: java, html, vaadin, vaadin21

In Vaadin 20 I could add an icon as a Java component:

`add(new Icon("vaadin", "check));`

or in HTML:

`<iron-icon icon=vaadin:check></iron-icon>`

Changing nothing but the Vaadin version, in Vaadin 21, the first shows an icon, the second is blank. I've gone through the Vaadin 21 documentation and there's nothing I can see about a formatting change, what's the deal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## *iron-icon* removed from Vaadin 21

I have no experience on this, but…

See [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68373324/642706) by [Jean-Christophe Gueriaud](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14668475/jean-christophe-gueriaud).

He explains that as part of the transition away from Polymer, *iron-icon* is no longer available in Vaadin 21 and later. The replacement is *vaadin-icon*.

[One user reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68348596/the-iron-icon-not-visible-with-a-master-detail-view-generate-with-vaadin-app-sta/68373324#comment120867688_68373324) that annotating `@Uses(Icon.class)` while replacing `iron-icon` with `vaadin-icon` in the template makes it work.

Perhaps the new doc pages [*Images and Icons*](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/application/resources#icons) and [*Vaadin Icons*](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/foundation/icons/vaadin) might help.